# How to upload a generated folder content into S3 using CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nuxt.js, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to configure a CodePipeline on AWS that it takes my Nuxt website on Github, run the command `npm run generate` to generate the static website then upload the `dist` folder on an S3 bucket.

Here what my `buildspec.yml` it looks like:

```sh
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run generate
  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 sync dist $S3_BUCKET
```

The error I get is: `The user-provided path dist does not exist.` Is anyone know how to correct this? I read a lot about artefacts but I never use them before…

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use artifacts to upload dist folder to s3. I will suggest not to use post build command to achieve this because the post build command runs even when the build is failed, this is the known limitation of codebuild. Just replace your buildspec with the following.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run generate
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: 'dist'
```

'**/*' means it will upload all the files and folder under the base directory "dist". You need to mention your bucket name in your aws console ( browser).
[image]
Also make sure that your codebuild IAM role has sufficient permission to access your bucket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I just have to add `- aws s3 sync dist $S3_BUCKET` under artifacts section?

Comment: @SébastienSerre No, there is no need to use that command. I have updated my answer please go through it.

Comment: Thanks! Is working great now :) My mistake was to pass by CodePipeline, I have redeployed everything using only CodeBuild as you describe and everything works